# What are the github buttons in repositories

Tags: github

I have used quite a lot of libraries from github, but I still don't understand buttons like below.
Could someone please tell me what those buttons mean?

[Github buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCnt6.png)
[These as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7wPk.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are ["shields" or "badges"](https://github.com/badges/shields), and they generally contain information about the repository.  Additionally, they are frequently clickable, leading you to a page with additional information or context. In these specific cases, I believe they mean:

- **pypi package 1.0.0**: That this library is at version `1.0.0` in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/)
- **Build: Passing**: That whatever build is in places is completing successfully
- **Test: Passing**: That all unit tests are passing
- **codecov: 80%**: Test coverage is at 80% of the code in the repository
- **Docs: Passing**: Not sure about this one-- but you could probably click it to learn more!
- **pypi: v0.14.0**: Similar to before-- the library in question is at version `0.14.0` in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/)
- **downloads: 3.8k/month**: This one is pretty self-explanatory-- the repo source gets downloaded ≈3,800 times per month (Most likely from PyPi, but *perhaps* from Github; again, you'd maybe want to click the badge for more context)
- **license: BSD**: The repository source is made available under a [BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)